# How do i save a dictionary of dictionaries created from a text file as acsv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

someone please help me with these 2 questions, am new to python language!

I want to create a dictionary of dictionaries from:

the  string below
    headers =" User-ID   Name   Password   Username Age"

and the tuple
    rows =("{:8}    {:8}     {:8}.format(user_id,  name,  password,  username, 
  age)

from a text file and save it as a csv file in python so that it comes out for example as:

```
{'User-ID  value1': {'Name': George, 'Password' : mygee, 'Username': Geo11, 
'Age' = 11},
'User-ID  value2': {'Name': Jennifer, 'Password' : jyloo, 'Username': Jen18, 
'Age' = 18},
'User-ID  value3': {'Name': Micheal, 'Password' : mycheee, 'Username': 
 Mic22, 'Age' = 22}}
```

Note:the user id is generated using a random function
    ID = random.randint(1,90000) .

Another problem noticed s that in the text file, the header is repeating each time i append a new row.

for example:

```
headers = " User-ID     Name   Password   Username Age"
with open(sometext.txt, 'w') as file1:
file1 .write(headers)
file1.close()

def newUser():

    global users
    global header

    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")
    if createLogin in users: # check if login name exists
        print("\nLogin name already exist, please choose a different name!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw # add login and 
         password
    #return (users[createLogin])
    surname = input("Pls enter your surname: ")
     name = input("Pls enter ur name: ")
     age = input("Pls enter your age: ")
     y_group = int(input("Please enter your year group: "))
     sex =input("Please enter your sex: ")
     print("\nUser created!\n") 
     print("*********************************")
     print(" Your Name is\t" + name, "and it starts with: " + name[0] + "\n")
     z1 = createPassw[:3] + age
     print(" Your Username is:\t ", z1)
```

Here we add any new user

```
  if __name__ =='__main__':
        if newUser():
            rows =("{:8}    {:8}     {:8}   {:8}     {:8}.format(user_id,  name,  password,  username, age))
        break
    with open(sometext.txt, 'a') as file2: 
          file2 .write(rows)
    file2.close()
```

Comment: Hi. You are expected to give a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: so i dont really know how to go about it. Thanks in advice for any help

Comment: Hi everyone please someone should kindly help me out with my question above

Comment: Do you really think it's okay to retrieve the UID from a random number generator? You could get the same number again.

Comment: Yea, that might not be much of a problem as i could also use the z1 variable for the same purpose. my main problems beng able to build the nested dictionary